# Differentiability at $(0,0)$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Consider the function

> $f\colon\mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R $
> $$f(x,y)=\begin{cases}x&\text{if $y = 0 $},\\ 
> x -  y^3\sin \left( \dfrac{1}{y} \right) &\text{if $ y \neq 0$}.\end{cases}$$
> Determine it's differentiability at $(0,0)$

The hint suggested to use the definition of differentiability given in Thomas' Calculus
[image]

So based on this I  was able to prove the function differentiable only considering the form for $\Delta y \neq 0$.

But the solution that was provided had an additional step determining the differentiability when $\Delta y = 0$ i.e., along paths where $\Delta y = 0$

In this case the LHS of the equation reduces to

$$ f(\Delta x, \Delta y) - f(0,0) = \Delta x \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, ...1$$

here, $f_x(0,0) = 1 \,\,\& \,\, f_y(0,0) = 0$
And the RHS of the equation form in the definition reduces to
$$ \Delta x f_x(0,0) + \Delta y f_y(0,0) +\Delta x\epsilon_1 +\Delta y\epsilon_2 = \Delta x +  \Delta x\epsilon_1 + 0\times\epsilon_2 =  \Delta x +  \Delta x\epsilon_1 \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, ...\,2$$
Equating 1 and 2 we get,
$$ \Delta x = \Delta x +  \Delta x\epsilon_1$$
$$ \Rightarrow \Delta x\epsilon_1 = 0 \Rightarrow \epsilon_1 = 0 $$
And based on this the solution said that the function is differentiable along $\Delta y = 0$.

My Question:
1.) Based on the definition we need both $\epsilon_1,\epsilon_2 \to 0$, but for the case $\Delta y = 0$ only showing $\epsilon_1 \to 0$ was considered sufficient, is this correct ,if yes , why is that so?
2.) The defintion of differentiability doesn't talk about paths so is checking the definition along paths correct?
3.)I was told that $\epsilon_1,\epsilon_2 $ are functions of $\Delta x\,\, \text{and} \,\,\Delta y$, but what do they represent in this definition?

Comment: To me the business with increments, while pedagogically understandable, clouds the issue: The function $g(x, y) = x$ is certainly differentiable. The difference $f - g$ satisfies $|f(x, y) - g(x, y)| \leq y^{3}$ for all $(x, y)$, even if $y = 0$. (!) <> Does that help with verifying the "linear approximation" in the definition?

Comment: But $|f(x,y)-g(x,y)| $ is not necessarily less than $y^3$ for all y take for eg. negative y. Also I'm not how $|f(x,y)-g(x,y)| $  would relate to the equation given in the definition.

Comment: Try $|f(x, y) - g(x, y)| \leq |y^3|$.

Comment: I'm not sure how $|f(x,y) - g(x,y)|$ would be applied here, the question was covered in a introductory class of multivariable calculus, the definition was not discussed in much detail.

Comment: I think Andrew's point was that $f$ is the sum of two differentiable functions. One of those functions is $g(x,y)$ and the other is $h(x,y) = f(x,y) - g(x,y)$.

Comment: You can use the fact that if the partial derivatives are continuous at $(0,0)$ then function is differentiable at $(0,0).$ Was it covered in your analysis course ?

Comment: My oops; as David notes, I lost the absolute values. <> The point here is, we can set $\epsilon_{2} = |\Delta y|^{3}/\Delta y$ for $\Delta y \neq 0$ (and $0$ for $\Delta y = 0$), so that $|\Delta y|^{3} = \epsilon_{2}\, \Delta y$. It's now enough to show $\epsilon_{2} \to 0$ as $\Delta y \to 0$.